# Unable to show a wrong password in login page

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a application running with a flask backend and angular frontend. Apparently when a wrong password is entered i want to show a error message. I have tried out ng-show and ng-if both nothing seems to work.
This is the html for my login page -

```html
<div layout="column" layout-align="center center" class="">
  <img class="logo" ng-src="assets/images/logo.png">
  <h1 class="md-display-2 login-heading">Login to Bassa</h1>
  <div layout="row">
    <md-input-container>
      <label>User name</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.user_name"/>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" ng-enter="login()"/>
    </md-input-container>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="login()">Login</md-button>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="signup()">Signup</md-button>
</div>
```

And this is the login controller -

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'UserService', LoginCtrl]);

  function LoginCtrl($scope, $state, UserService) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.incorrectCredentials = false;

    $scope.login = function(){
      UserService.login($scope.user, function(status) {
        if (status){
          $state.go('home.dashboard');
        } else {
          $scope.incorrectCredentials = true;
        }
      });
    };

    $scope.signup = function() {
      $state.go('signup');
    };

    UserService.removeToken();
  }

})();
```

When the incorrectCredentials becomes true , i want to show a message.
After logging the User service -

```
  var login = function(credentials, cb) {
  var $http = $injector.get('$http');

  return $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: BassaUrl + '/api/login',
      transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join('&');
      },
      data: credentials,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }).then(function (response) {
    setToken(response.headers()['token']);
    setName(credentials.user_name);
    setAuthLevel(response.data.auth);
    console.log(response);
    cb(true);
  }, function(error){
    console.log("hello i am here")
    cb(false);
  });
};
```

I received a response log -

```
Object {data: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final/…ead-protected or not readable by the server.</p>↵", status: 403, config: Object, statusText: "FORBIDDEN"}
```

It isn't entering the error block , which prevents me from prompting wrong password message.

Comment: `<span ng-show="incorrectCredentials">Invalid password!</span>` should work fine. You don't seem to have an ng-show in the code you posted...?

Comment: I just tried this out , doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you sure your code reaches the `$scope.incorrectCredentials = true;` line? Try to add a `console.log("I'M HERE")` on the line before that. Can you also post your `UserService` code?

Comment: @Fissio is right. If you say it doesn't work, then you should confirm if the condition for `$scope.incorrectCredentials` becoming true is met

Comment: Here is the user service code-[link]https://github.com/saisankargochhayat/Bassa/blob/master/ui/src/app/common/UserService.js

Comment: @SaisankarGochhayat Then the problem lies within your `UserService.login` call. Add a `console.log(response)` in the `.then(function() { ... })` of your login function and see what's in there, and continue debugging from there. :)

Comment: @Fissio it returns a 403 object , 'Object {data: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final/…ead-protected or not readable by the server.</p>↵", status: 403, config: Object, statusText: "FORBIDDEN"}'  , i guess its because of the abort from the flask server - https://codepaste.net/hrzxdf

Comment: Weird, it should jump to the error handler since the the status code is outside the range of `200-299`. You may want to start a new question with the response you got and your UserService code. The LoginCtrl code should be fine though.

Comment: @Fissio is it because of the backend sending a 403 abort ? https://github.com/scorelab/Bassa/blob/master/components/core/REST.py ,line 86 .

Comment: Sorry that was happening due to the interceptor , my bad , @Fissio thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually my own fault. My custom Interceptor simply swallowed authentication errors.